# Insert custom cell in between rows in tableview - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to display a date picker below the row that was clicked (similar to the one shown in the image)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 2
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DailyTimesTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DailyTimesTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

How can I insert datePickerCell below the row that was selected (as shown in the image), appreciate your help.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Here I am trying to insert datePickerCell below the selected row (as shown in the image)
    let datePickerCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DatePickerTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DatePickerTableViewCell

    var rowNumber  = indexPath.row + 1
    var newIndexPath = IndexPath()
    newIndexPath.row = rowNumber

    tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)

}
```

[image]

Comment: First thing I see is your numberOfRowsInSection is 2 but when you click , you try to add a third row. Did you get any error?

Comment: I don't get any errors because the cell is not being inserted.

Comment: There's a few problems here, you can't just insert a row like this. You are telling the tableview that there are 2 rows always in the numberOfRowsInSection function, so you can never insert or remove a row. You need to a use some kind of data set like an array to set how many rows there will be, that way if you add or remove data in the array you can update the tableview accordingly.

Comment: instead of adding new row to tableview , you can expand your current cell. Here is a tutorial http://codepany.com/blog/swift-3-expandable-table-view-cells/